# "Update to" table values not loading during simple update query

Tags: ms-access

Started a new job with the most recent version of Access and can't find an answer to this -

When doing a basic Update query linking two tables I want to update a field in Table 1 to a field in Table 2 - every version I've had for the past 20 years gives you a drop down menu of the table fields available in the "Update to:" line but not this version?? I can type it out of course but I miss my drop down menu. Any ideas how to get this back?

Thanks in advance for any help.

Comment: Not quite sure I'm following... are you trying to `update` values in Table 2 with values from Table 1 or are you trying to `join` them together? Is this query in a VBA macro or a Query Design query?

Comment: Update values from one table to another. Just doing a very simple Update query designed in Access? On the grid you see in Design view there is the "Update to": row and usually that has a drop down menu that lists all the fields available in the tables. That drop down menu is not there and that is what I am trying to get.Thanks so much for your help!!!

Comment: No problem. I left an answer below.

Answer (score 0):

In Access 2013, go to `Design > Query Type` in the ribbon and select `Update`. The grid will change to show your `Update To:` dropdown.

[image: Query Type option]

Comment: Thank you - I have tried that - the drop down is just not there - it's bizarre!

Comment: @EllieW That is bizarre! What fields show in the grid for the `Select` and `Update` query types?

Comment: Right?? No fields at all - all I can do is type them in i.e. [Table1].[Field1]. I use Update to all the time this is going to drive me nuts! It will auto fill in Functions if I start to type them though. Well thanks anyway.